# python pyqt5 add file name to getSaveFileName

Tags: python, pyqt5, qfiledialog

I'm trying to add a default name to `QFileDialog()` the images below illustrate.

This is what I get (no filename)

[image: What I get]

and this is what I want to achieve without having to input it manually, I want to pass the `file_name` threw a function and have that name show up there.
[image]

This is the code im trying to make to work:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5 import *
import sys
class mainwindowUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mainwindowUI, self).__init__()
        self.exportFiles('test.mp3')
    def exportFiles(self,file_name):
        filename, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save audio file", "", "Audio Files (*.mp3)")
        if filename:
            print(filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = mainwindowUI()
    app.exec_()
```

I tried to add options:

```py
filename, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save audio file", "", "Audio Files (*.mp3)", options=QFileDialog.setLabelText(file_name))
```

But this is incorrect and i have no idea how to make it work...

Anyone know how to add a file name to save file dialog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The third argument indicates the initial name:

```
def exportFiles(self, file_name):
    default_dir ="/home/qt_user/Documents"
    default_filename = os.path.join(default_dir, file_name)
    filename, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(
        self, "Save audio file", default_filename, "Audio Files (*.mp3)"
    )
    if filename:
        print(filename)
```

Comment: That works perfectly, but What if I want to add a default directory location?

Comment: @JareBear So you have to concatenate the default directory with the file_name

Comment: This works perfectly! Exactly what i wanted, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

First create a save-as action

```
self.saveas=QAction(QtGui.QIcon('saveas.png'),'save-as')
```

Add the save-as action to toolbar

```
toolbar=self.addToolbar('toolbar');
toolbar.addAction(self.saveas);
```

Sub this for your QFileDialog code

```
Fn, _=QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,'export pdf',file_name,'Pdf files(.pdf);;All files()');
```

when connecting the signal to the slot do this

```
Self.Saveas.toggled.connect(self.exportfiles('name of default file');
```

Comment: Your answer has some important issues. The `toggled` signal only works for checkable actions, so in this case the `triggered` signal should be used instead. That line also has wrong capitalization, the parenthesis is not closed (also, the semicolons are unnecessary) and the argument for the connection should be a callable, while in that case it will execute the call to `exportfiles` immediately and return None as soon as the dialog is closed, causing a crash.

Comment: Also, while QAction should accept a constructor without parent, in PyQt (at least up to 5.7) the parent argument is required in the constructor, so it's usually better to add it when creating standalone actions.